# Unexpected response code 500 for a POST request in Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am making a POST request using Volley to http://api.weddingonclick.com/vendor/auths/

When I am using [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) the response comes fine

```
{
  "msg": "OTP sent"
}
```

But when I am sending the request using Volley I get ServerError
I was using the same code before and it was working fine. Suddenly it started giving me this error.

My code:

```
StringRequest firstTimeStringRequest = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.POST,
            "http://api.weddingonclick.com/vendor/auths/", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String responseString) {
            Snackbar.make(sendButton, responseString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Snackbar.make(sendButton, error.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("mobile", "1234567890");
            params.put("action", "sign_in");
            params.put("a_session", ""+41);
            params.put("a_source", "VENDOR_APP");
            return params;
        }

    };
    firstTimeStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(firstTimeStringRequest);
```

For debugging I created a requestbin and sent request from both POSTMAN and my app. I can't seem to find a difference.

EDIT: I sent more requests to the requestbin by mistake. Please consider the first and second requests only from bottom

Here is the requestbin http://requestb.in/13j4apk1?inspect

Please Help

Comment: The server expects a POST request with the parameters that are mentioned in my code. I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Please learn HTTP basics ... server expects some kind of content in some type (you send some content without any type (json, binary,plain text, etc ... )... without knowing API requirements it is imposible to say that

Comment: @Ishan: any updates?

Answer (score 0):

**Sometime cases:**

This is not your library problem, browsers usually ignore error 500 in headers and display the content but volley dose not do that and call onErrorResponse. I think this is a server side application problem but you can get your response in onErrorResponse. in order to convince yourself you can add RESTClient mozilla add on and send your volley request and see the response. in the header it shows you error 500 internal server error but you can see the response in the body section

Comment: As I have mentioned that sending the request using POSTMAN works. So this can't be the server error.... And how can I see the response in onErrorResponse? onErrorResponse only gives me a VolleyError object and not the response body.

Comment: @Ishan I mention the title Sometime cases.

Comment: I saw the title. But it is happening to me all the time. What to do ?